# Can I copy over React project's src folder to another project?

Tags: reactjs

I have react js code from machine 1.

```
machine 1: project in progress
machine 2: fresh install of create-react-app script.
```

Can I copy over (overwrite) src folder from machine 1 to machine 2? Will it work? Or I need to run some commands from machine 2 after copying? Or is this impossible?

I'm expecting to have the same project for both machines. Both are windows machines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to have the same project on both machines, then just copy all the files (entire project directory including `package.json`) except for `./node_modules` directory (you can also remove it after you copy). Then on the target machine run `npm install` to re-create missing `node_modules` directory.

Depending on your situation, a more appropriate way to do this could be to use version control software like Git.

Comment: Agreed, just one little thing, all files except `node_modules` and then run `npm install`

Comment: Agree, use version control. It will be beneficial for you especially when you interchange on using both machines for your projects

Comment: Thanks @AaminKhan. That's a good point considering that machines may have different OS / CPU architectures. +1

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the contents but the `node_modules`. After you copied the files access the root folder and run in:
`npm install`
(do this to avoid slow copying for the folder structure)
But as Tad mentioned a version control system would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended method is to:

1. Create a new directory: # mkdir new_dir
2. Copy all the contents of your current project, except "node_modules" directory.
3. Must include package-lock.json to maintain package versions across parallel installs.
4. Now, navigate to the "new_dir" & run: npm install
5. This will install all the packages required & should work without any issues